# Elasticsearch index refresh from kibana giving 403 error on kubernetes (ECK cluster)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to refresh an index pattern from kibana and getting 403 error. I have no heap issues/ RAM issues.

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"index [.kibana_1] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];: [cluster_block_exception] index [.kibana_1] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];"}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383601/aws-elastic-search-forbidden-8-index-write-api-unable-to-write-to-index